# E-Commerce Reporting Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight-4.0, reporting-services

We are planned to write the Reporting solution for our compmany (internal may be hosted in our internal server visible to top management).

Reporting solution will needs to done the following things

1. Data Visualization like Dundas Dashboard
2. Different combination report displayed in Grid and export to excel

We are the Component developer so we already having the Powerful Tools, Chart, Grid, Gage controls in both SL and MVC platforms.

Which is the best platform to choose reporting application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SSRS and SSAS would be better even it's not perfect.  It would meet your requirements, using SSRS to develop and produce reports and SSAS/cubes to produce dashboards. It provides a web portal to host all reports and other objects. It also can be integrated to your other apps and enterprise solutions by leverage SSAS/SSRS web services.

Even though Silverlight4 provides some BI components, but I doubt it can be served as a report solution as it less other report tools and functions.